# Testing solar panels by covering one up out of 18 panels. If the voltage drops, is the panel defective?

Tags: voltage, power, solar-cell, power-output-stage

The panels produce 31.4 V under load 45V open circuit, 4.1 amperes under load.

I used to have a load voltage of around 271V for 18 panels in two strings of 9 in parallel.  The voltage is now about 180V in good sun and output per day dropped from
15 kW to around 8kW per day.

I would think that the voltage will drop if the panel is good and go up if panel is bad.  That is, drop to 198 V when shaded. The bypass diode should come into play.

Comment: If you cover one panel then the voltage should drop by the voltage produced by that panel less the diode voltage. But work on one string at a time.

Comment: (@SolarMike *voltage produced **plus** the diode voltage drop*?!)

Comment: `output per day dropped from 15 kW` kWh, presumably. (271 V \* 8.2 A is about 2.2  kW - figures.) How much does daily insolation vary where the panels are installed? Are the panels clean, their cover clear? What about panel temperature? Strikingly, the voltage is about 6/9 of the original.

Comment: More data is required. Let's start with the obvious: At what latitude are you located, and at what time(s) of the year were the two sets of measurements taken?

Comment: readings taken at same time 1 pm afternoon  latitude 25 deg south australia temperature 32 deg cent